# Apache VirtualHost - Simulate $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, redirect, https

I'm trying to simulate adding this into wp-config.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Except in a format that executes in Apache "Virtual Host Include". From what I understand, this essentially tells Wordpress that SSL is enabled.

All my sites use CloudFlare Flexible SSL (force https redirect in CF), none of them have a certificate from AutoSSL/cPanel.

Without using this code, going to /wp-admin will result in a redirect loop. But it's very time-consuming to have to go through and add the code to all current and future domains.

I've tried a million codes, but none of them work. Here's an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know the correct Include Editor/VirtualHost code to accomplish this? I just need to tell Wordpress that SSL is on, despite not having a valid certificate in cPanel. I use CF SSL for all of my sites.

Or, maybe I'm completely off and need to edit a different file to accomplish this?

Running CentOS 7.8/WHM 90.0.5/Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching, I finally found the answer.

Add to Pre Main Include (pre_main_global.conf):

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
</IfModule>
```